# Prove that any maximal interval of existence is open

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to prove that any maximal interval of existence is open.

Let $J ⊂ \mathbb R$ be a non-empty open interval, let $E$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^N$ and let $f : J × E → \mathbb R^N$ be continuous. Assume that $x : I → \mathbb R^N$  is a maximal solution of the differential equation $\dot x(t) = f(t, x(t))$. I want to show that the maximal interval of existence
$I$ is open.

I don't know how to prove this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some context. Do you refer to a specific type of differential equation? If so, which one?

Comment: I can only guess from you tag that you are talking about the maximal solution of a differential equation.

Comment: @NicolòRuggeri My bad, I have added some context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple consequence of the definition of maximal interval, which has always to do with some initial condition. And the union of *any* family of open intervals containing some time $t_0$ is always an open interval.

*EDITED:* <strike>What is more delicate to prove is that the maximal interval only depends on the initial condition, *even* if the solutions are not unique.</strike>

Comment: I am afraid that what you mentioned in the last paragraph is not "delicate to prove", but false. Consider $f(x)=0$ for $x\le0$, $=2\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in(0,1)$, and $=2x^2$ for $x>1$. The trivial solution of the IVP $\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$, $x(0)=0$, has $(-\infty,\infty)$ as its maximal interval of existence, whereas the solution $\varphi(t)=0$ for $t<0$, $\varphi(t)=t^2$ for $t\in[0,1]$ and $\varphi(t)=\frac{1}{3-2t}$ for $t>1$ is defined on $(-\infty,\frac{3}{2})$.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks for pointing it out, quite nice example. Answer corrected accordingly.

Comment: Why should every interval containing $t_0$ be open?

Comment: @user7802048 By definition: in this simple context solutions are **by definition** $C^1$ functions on open intervals. In other contexts you can and must in fact consider other notions of solution.

Comment: @JohnB In my lecture we did consider closed intervals as well (while looking at the corresponding integral equation $y(t) = y_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s, y(s)) \,ds$). In this case the maximal interval of existence is still open in any case.

Comment: @user7802048 Great. As I said: In other contexts [such as for integral equations] you can and must in fact consider other notions of solution. It always depends on the definition. But when we consider integral equations, the advantage is that we can consider functions $f$ that are not continuous, not that the interval is not open. As you said: it can be made open when $f$ is continuous. But not in general.